# Log in using Credential Providers

Tags: c++, authentication, winapi, credential-providers

Please, somebody explain me how to create a working Credential Provider! I am using the HardwareEventCredentialProvider sample as a base to build my own Provider on top of. I've changed username and password fields, but it seems doesn't work. After submiting credentials to a system I only see a blank screen for a sec. or receive a message "Incorrect password or username" and then authentication starts again...
What I need to do in `GetSerialization()` and `SetSerialization()` methods to log in with existing user?(username=L"virt naXa!", password=L"1234")

I've read "Credential Provider Technical Reference" and Dan Griffin's article about CPs in Vista and still don't understand how can I log in using credential providers. (Maybe I've done it not carefully and need to reread them?)

And I'm sorry for my bad English, it's not my native language:)

Comment: Show us your code please, and we can help.

Comment: Hey, guys! Have you successfully forgotten this question?

Comment: You project is VC++, and that link points off to a site I'm not going to click on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*It's been awhile since I asked this question...*

I remember only that thereat I reread [this article](https://habr.com/ru/post/83384/) (in Russian) and **carefully** followed the example in order to create my own Credential Provider. And it worked!

Unfortunately, the source codes provided by the author of that article are not available anymore. And here you can find another sample of [Credential Provider](https://github.com/laie/CustomCredentialProvider).

Answer (score 0):

Download the MSDN samples and customize them from [here (new link)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4057).

they are actually a little bit outdated, but they still do work!

Comment: @toster-cx added new link